# Why is my cast List<String> not matching?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Simplified Question:**

Starting with `dynamic x = [a, b]` where a and b are `String`.

The following cast fails, i.e. the print out is 'fail':

```
if(x is List<String>){
  print('pass');
} else{
  print('fail');
}
```

I think the above is the simplified version of my question, but in case you need more info, see below for more detailed version.

**More Detailed Question (if needed)**

I have a `dynamic` List that can be any number of levels deep. For example, it may start like this:

```
x = [a, [b, c, d], [e, [f, g, h], i]]
```

Where each letter above is a String. I'm looping through to unwrap it and can catch it when it gets to the final String by doing:

```
if(x is String) { ... } // Works!
```

But, when I try to catch it one level before becoming a `String`, `List<String>` it will never match. For example, the following doesn't work EVEN when the dynamic it is given is a `List<String>`:

```
if(x is List<String>) {...} // Doesn't work
```

Why isn't `List<String>` ever true?

More complete example:

```
x = [a, [b, c, d], [e, [f, g, h], i]]
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x is List<String>){ ... } // Never works even if print(x) prints [b, c, d]
    else if(x is String){ ... } //Works!
    else { ... } // Works obviously
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might declare `b`, `c`, and `d` as dynamic, Flutter considers as `List<dynamic>`, so you have to give typed `List` as following..

```
x = [a, <String>[b, c, d], [e, <String>[f, g, h], i]]
```

**Or**

You have to check with dynamic `List`

```
if (x is List) { ... }
```

Comment: So the dynamic lists (i.e. x) is already determined and there are tons of them, all slightly different. So I can't declare the <String> as far as I can tell. That's why I'm trying to detect it instead. Your second option works to identify the List, but then List can be `List<dynamic>` (i.e. `List<List<List...>>` or `List<String>` or something else), so I'm trying to capture the instance where it's `List<String>` only. Maybe I can do `if(x is List && SOMETHING ELSE)`?

Comment: @Coltuxumab You can test every element with `x.every((e) => e is String)`.